# jQuery: syntax error (mm-menu)

Tags: jquery

After adding navbars lines into code below, code stopped working, what is wrong?

Console says:-

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list".

Could you please tell me, where i have to insert ) ?

[My site.](http://hostelsiiram.fi/)

```js
$("#main-menu").mmenu({
    "extensions": [
      "pagedim-black",
      "position-right",
      "theme-dark"
    ]
  },
  "navbars": [{
    "position": "top",
    "type": "tabs",
    "content": [
      "<a href='#main-menu'>Menu</a>",
      "<a href='#languages'>Language</a>"
    ]
  }], {
    // configuration
    offCanvas: {
      pageSelector: "#my-page"
    },
    clone: true
  });
```

Comment: You’re closing the object after the `extensions` entry already with `}`, but then you go on as if you were still inside the object, by trying to specify another key ...

Comment: Man, you have a syntax error there. Open debugger in chrome or whatever browser you use and do debugging.

Comment: Pasting your code into the `<>` snippet editor and clicking TIDY shows clearly you have an issue with closing brackets

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [mmenu example details](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/core/options.html)

Code need to be:-

```
$("#main-menu").mmenu({
       "extensions": [
          "pagedim-black",
          "position-right",
          "theme-dark"
       ], 
        "navbars":{
           "position": "top",
           "type": "tabs",
           "content": [
              "<a href='#main-menu'>Menu</a>",
              "<a href='#languages'>Language</a>"
           ]
        }
   },{
    offCanvas: {
      pageSelector: "#my-page"
    },
   "clone": true
});
```

Comment: Yes, no errors anymore! thank you, Alive to Die, for helping and explaining! i'm really novice in javascript world, please don't beat me!

Comment: @Gallex  glad to help you :):)